# Get information from tree parent as column

Tags: mysql, tree, recursive-query

I've got data with geographical locations. That may be cities, provinces, states, countries, continents, or whatever kind of location. A location can be part of an other location, like a State is part of a Country (like the US), but The Netherlands has provinces. Cities can be in a Province but they aren't necessarily part of a province. Partly because some cities are city-state(-like) (i.e. Luxembourg), but in my case it's not even relevant in what province a city is, if there's only one city from a country in my locations list.

This this very simple example:

```
| types     |
|-----------|
| Continent |
| Country   |
| Province  |
| City      |


Locations

| id | name          | type      | parent |
|----|---------------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | Europe        | Continent | NULL   |
| 2  | Netherlands   | Country   | 1      |
| 3  | Noord-Holland | Province  | 2      |
| 4  | Amsterdam     | City      | 3      |
| 5  | Haarlem       | City      | 3      |
| 6  | Luxembourg    | City      | 1      |
```

For every location I want to know their 'geographical parent' (if exist). So the expected outcome is this:

```
| id | name          | type      | Continent | Country     | Province      |
|----|---------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|---------------|
| 1  | Europe        | Continent |           |             |               |
| 2  | Netherlands   | Country   | Europe    |             |               |
| 3  | Noord-Holland | Province  | Europe    | Netherlands |               |
| 4  | Amsterdam     | City      | Europe    | Netherlands | Noord-Holland |
| 5  | Haarlem       | City      | Europe    | Netherlands | Noord-Holland |
| 6  | Luxembourg    | City      | Europe    |             |               |
```

How can I get all `types` as a column for my Locations table? I've tried to use subqueries, but I'm completely stuck because of the recursiveness: Amsterdam is not part of a country (but it's Province is), while Luxembourg is part of a country (without a Province).

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there is a better solution but at the moment I wrote this:

```
SELECT Locations.id,
       Locations.name,
       Locations.type,
       IF(l3.name IS NULL, IF(l2.name IS NULL, IFNULL(l1.name, ''), l2.name), l3.name) as Continent,
       IF(l3.name IS NULL, IF(l2.name IS NULL, '', l1.name), l2.name)                  as Country,
       IF(l3.name IS NULL, '', l1.name)                                                as Province
FROM Locations
         LEFT join Locations l1 on Locations.parent = l1.id
         LEFT join Locations l2 on l1.parent = l2.id
         LEFT join Locations l3 on l2.parent = l3.id
ORDER BY Locations.id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/8)

Comment: For the sake of readability I've simplified my question. Unfortunately, now I see I've simplified it too much and it doesn't reflect my problem. But that's my fault and given this question, this is a great answer. Thanks!